# Javascript Get the text in a particular table cell in (this) row

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a table that's created dynamically.
Each row have a button.

When I let on the button on a row I want it to get the text in a particular cell.

Something like this:

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1 Here</td>
        <td>Other Text Here</td>
        <td><button onclick="getData(this.cell[1].innerHtml)">Get Data</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this using pure javascript or typescript?

Comment: Share your JS code which shows what you have done so far to achieve this and what problems/error you are facing.

Comment: I've shared all I have. I don't know how to get that data at runtime from a table cell so I can't do anymore until I do

Comment: You can use `.siblings()' or 'closest('td')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the first cells text to do that you can use `parentNode`/`childNodes` to get a list of all the `tds` in the row and then pick the one you want by the index.

```js
function getData(x)
{
console.log(x.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerHTML)
console.log(x.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1 Here</td>
        <td>Other Text Here</td>
        <td><button onclick="getData(this)">Get Data</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your setup for the getData function, `this` will refer to the button that was clicked - buttons don't have a "cell" property.

I would suggest:

```
<button onclick="getData(this)">Get Data</button>
```

then

```
function getData(btn) {
  var tr = btn.parentNode.parentNode; // the parent of btn is the td, the parent of td is the tr.
  var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; // get the first TD in the TR
  console.log(td.innerHTML); // log the content of the TD
}
```